# React Native Expo - unable to create Apple Provisioning Profile - not in the list of the created apps

Tags: react-native, expo

I am using expo to build my app. Each time I run expo build:ios

```
We are missing the following credentials from you: Apple Distribution Certificate, Apple Push Notifications service key, Apple Provisioning Profile
? How would you like to upload your credentials? Expo handles all credentials, y
ou can still provide overrides
? Will you provide your own Apple Distribution Certificate? Let Expo handle the 
process
✔ Didn't find any previously uploaded Apple Distribution Certificate
? Will you provide your own Apple Push Notifications service key? Let Expo handl
e the process
✔ Didn't find any previously uploaded Apple Push Notifications service key
✖ Something went wrong when trying to ensure App ID exists on Apple Developer Portal!
/Users/michal/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin/traveling-fastlane-1.11.3-osx/ensure_app_exists exited with non-zero code: 1
```

In reality, I have all of those apart from Provisioning Profile which I can not create as my app is not in the list of created applications. I have spent a half a month developing the app being approved by the client and working on Android, but I am unable to push to production for iOS. I am struggling with this for 5th day. Can anyone help, please? I tried to do this manually but even that will fail as I am missing the provisioning key. When I try to do it myself the app is simply not in the list of the apps. Any thoughts on how to do this?

UPDATE: I have just created a completely new blank test app (default expo one) and run the same command `expo build: ios` as per https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/distribution/building-standalone-apps/
I get exactly the same reply. Is there any intermediary step that is not described in the documentation. Like me going into dev portal and doing there something (registering the app manually)? I am confused. I thought this is meant to be straight forward.

UPDATE: Running `expo doctor` I am getting the following message:
`Didn't find any issues with your project!`

UPDATE: Running `expo diagnostics` I am getting the following:

```
  Expo CLI 3.11.3 environment info:
    System:
      OS: macOS 10.15.2
      Shell: 5.7.1 - /bin/zsh
    Binaries:
      Node: 13.5.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
      Yarn: 1.21.1 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
      npm: 6.13.4 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: 3.5 AI-191.8026.42.35.6010548
      Xcode: 11.3.1/11C504 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      expo: ^36.0.0 => 36.0.2 
      react: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0 
      react-native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-36.0.1.tar.gz => 0.61.4 
      react-navigation: ^4.0.10 => 4.0.10
```

Comment: You should try to login to Apple Developer Portal to see if your app id is already registered

Comment: hi @JarvisLuong thanks for the comment. I am in the Apple Developer Portal and as per my description when trying to manually create provisioning profile I can not see the app in the list. It was my hope that I can go around this problem by providing all the certificates myself. I have created key, p12, p8 certificate but I am unable to create provisioning one as the app is simly not listed in the list of apps there (I can see 20 of them there but none of them is the one I am trying to publish). Any idea?

Comment: Hmm, did you change the app id to something unique?

Comment: @JarvisLuong does not seem to me like an issue with that app. I have created a new one called test and tried to do push with exactly the same result. Its almost as if I should do the certificates myself or if the cli would not work at all. Is the documentation complete? I mean is `expo build:ios` all I need to type into terminald and all will work or do I need to do something in the developer account - like creating the certificates myself?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have proper access enable this checkbox in for your user in apple developer profile
"Access to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles."